# ether js decoding error while fetching struct array data

Tags: solidity, abi, ethers.js

I'm trying to create messenger dapp. Everything is fine until I tried to invoke messages of metamask logged in user.

Here is the messenger.sol file

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.8.0 <0.9.0;

struct Message {
    string from;
    string message;
}

contract Messenger {
    //Message public message;
    mapping(string => address) private nameToAddressLookup;
    mapping(address => string) private addressToNameLookup;
    mapping(string => Message[]) private userMessages;

    function send(
        string calldata toName,
        string calldata data
    ) public returns (bool) {
        address _fromAdd = msg.sender;
        address _toAdd = nameToAddressLookup[toName];

        string memory from = addressToNameLookup[_fromAdd];
        string memory _to = addressToNameLookup[_toAdd];

        Message memory message = Message(from, data);
        userMessages[_to].push(message);
        return true;
    }

    function register(string calldata name) public {
        //add to address to name mapping
        addressToNameLookup[msg.sender] = name;
        //add to name to address mapping
        nameToAddressLookup[name] = msg.sender;
    }

    function getMessages() public view returns (Message[] memory) {
        return userMessages[addressToNameLookup[msg.sender]];
    }
}
```

Here is the chatbox.js file

```
const ABI = [
    "function register(string name)",
    "function send(string toName, string data) public returns (bool)",
    "function getMessages() public view returns (tuple(string from, string message)[] messages)"
];

    import { ethers } from "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ethers/6.5.1/ethers.min.js";
    
    const CONTRACT_ADDRESS = "0x......"
    
    const provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(window.ethereum);
    
    await provider.send("eth_requestAccounts", []);
    
    const signer = await provider.getSigner();
    
    const contract = new ethers.Contract(CONTRACT_ADDRESS, ABI, signer);
    
    const getMessages = async () => {
        const messages = await contract.getMessages();
        console.log(messages);
    }
    
    getMessages();
```

Here is the error when called getMessages();

```
"_: overflow (argument="value", value=1401516635601752328688129939779608405649127233858, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=6.5.1)
    at makeError (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ethers/6.5.1/ethers.min.js:1:2378)
    at assert$1 (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ethers/6.5.1/ethers.min.js:1:2661)
    at assertArgument (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ethers/6.5.1/ethers.min.js:1:2741)
    at getNumber (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ethers/6.5.1/ethers.min.js:1:8325)
    at toNumber (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ethers/6.5.1/ethers.min.js:1:8896)
    at Reader.readIndex (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ethers/6.5.1/ethers.min.js:1:43846)
    at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ethers/6.5.1/ethers.min.js:1:120515
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at unpack (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ethers/6.5.1/ethers.min.js:1:120448)
    at TupleCoder.decode (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ethers/6.5.1/ethers.min.js:1:126020)"
```

As you can see ethers.js is not able to decode, scratching my head to find a solution.

Thanks in advance.